# Как подключить links в admin LTD?

Tags: php, yii2, phpmyadmin

в Yii2 site поделён на fronted, backend и common. в vendor подключен модуль блога, статей, тегов и т.д. Как сделать вкладку (link) слева в админке (backend)?
В  backand/veiws/layouts/left.php прописал: `['label' => 'Теги', 'icon' => 'tags', 'url' => ['/tag']], что ещё необходимо?`

Comment: Смотря что Вы хотите в итоге увидеть. Того что Вы уже написали будет достаточно для работы ссылки. Опишите конкретнее что хотите увидеть или что не работает сейчас с такой реализацией.

Comment: Сейчас если зайти на http://interjobs.com/site/index (на локалке) то там все стандартно:Home, About, Contact,Signup,Login. В backend (http://admin.interjobs.com/article) есть вкладка 'страницы' . В типах можно выбрать: cтраница, новость, акция'  И там есть ЧПУ созданной http://setDominInBackendConfig/article/one?url=1.  если перейти так http://admin.interjobs.com/article/article/view?id=2 Как сделать, чтобы она была в какой-нибудь вкладке 'статьи',  во fronted, а другая созданная  во вкладке -'новости', к примеру, также во fronted?